# how to launch Console Application(!) on startup? C#

Tags: c#, console-application, startup

I've tried to create a Console Application program, and cause the application to run on startup.
I found some solutions, but they uses external dll files (Of the operation system, in my case - Windows) or they refers to Windows Forms / WPF. I've realized that the startup code for Windows Forms application is pretty different than from a Console Application's startup code..
Can Someone help me? I really confused now..

Here's the code I found: (on this url: [How to run a C# application at Windows startup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5089601/run-the-application-at-windows-startup))

```
RegistryKey rkApp = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);
rkApp.SetValue("MyAPP", Application.ExecutablePath.ToString());
```

How can I do this action for a console application, with code that will be similar to this one, and without using external dlls?

Thanks..

Answer (score 4):

`Application.ExecutablePath` is only used by Windows apps.  To get the executing assembly of any app, use `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location`:

```
RegistryKey rkApp = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);
rkApp.SetValue("MyAPP", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
```

Comment: will this work for other platforms like macos and linux. I want my console app to be started automatically like we do on windows startup apps.

Answer (score 2):

You've already got the right solution. The `Registry` classes in the .NET framework don't require WinForms or WPF references, so you're free to use them in a console application without littering your project with unnecessary references.

Comment: but when i'm trying to use this in my code, it gives me an error in the part "Application.ExecutablePath.ToString()" in the second line.. why is this happening?

Comment: @Aviv you never mention that in your original question, edit your question and please include that information and what the error says in your post.

Comment: Try Assembly.GetEntryAssembly() instead