# launch a .net application using log records

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

I want to run a application automatically when a user logs on to the system.
The application must get itself launched when the user logs on to the system for the first time on a day.

I tried to open event viewer. I can find all records related to logon details.But how can I use that records to launch my application is where I am stuck!

example:
I am going to office in the morning 9:00 am, my computer ill be in lock state. When I login to the system for the first time in that -the application must be launched.
Only for the first log in.
How can i do this?

please assist me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5089601/run-the-application-at-windows-startup

Comment: log in title is misleading. Its more of startup script is what you need

Comment: Like CarbineCoder mentioned, you may write a batch script to what you need and create a service for that and put it automatic.

Comment: yes carbine....please assist me